# How to put the footer below the Viewport, when there is less content?

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I'm working on a website in which sometimes the pages might not cover the entire height of the screen (due to less content), which creates empty white space below the footer. I'm trying to solve this by always keeping the footer below the viewport. I've tried many ways to do this, but all of them solve one problem and create another.

Here is a [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qF69E/) for what I have so far.

The only time it actually worked was when I set `height:100%` to the body and html, but this makes the content overflow the body in the DOM, which I'm trying to avoid. Also, because the site needs a boxed layout, I need to wrap the page-content and footer with the #page-wrapper div as used in the code.

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this, with the given markup.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Here is a slightly updated [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qF69E/2/)

Comment: Hi, are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/qF69E/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. The footer can be below the fold or sticking at the bottom as you showed; however, with your code if there is more content, then the footer doesn't get pushed down by the content and always stays in that position.

Comment: you have to use position:fixed. I think that is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/qF69E/3/

Comment: But that would always keep the footer at the bottom of the screen. I want the footer to get pushed down if there is more content, but if there is less content, I don't want to have any space between the footer and the bottom of the screen.

Comment: So the footer should always be visible but there should never be a space between content and footer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by absolutely positioning the footer and making the page-wrapper relatively positioned. The catch is that you'll have to size the page-wrapper using JS based on the height of the HTML element. Something like:

```
$('#page-wrapper').height($('html').height());
```

but you may need to tweak the position quite a bit unless you use

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```